# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' when working with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

i am trying to make a face mask recognition here, whenever i try to create my TF record an import problem pops up, i have tried to install pandas with condas and with pip3 the problem is that when i just import pandas it runs without problem but when i start the generate_tfrecord.py this problem shows up,
here is my code so far

```
WORKSPACE_PATH = "Tensorflow/workspace"
SCRIPTS_PATH = "Tensorflow/scripts"
APIMODEL_PATH = "Tensorflow/models"
ANNOTATION_PATH = WORKSPACE_PATH + "/annotations"
IMAGE_PATH = WORKSPACE_PATH + "/images"
MODEL_PATH = WORKSPACE_PATH + "/models"
PRETRAINED_MODEL_PATH =  WORKSPACE_PATH + "/pre-trained-models"
CONFIG_PATH = MODEL_PATH + '/my_ssd_mobnet/pipeline.config'
CHECKPOINT_PATH = MODEL_PATH + '/my_ssd_mobnet/'
```

and here is the command

```
!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x {IMAGE_PATH + '/train'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/train.record'}
```

and here is the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 21, in <module>
import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Comment: You apparently have multiple installations of Python.  You need to install `pandas` in whichever one is being used here.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `pip install pandas` in your CMD it might solve your problem.

Comment: well i tried with pip and pip3 and even with conda and the same problem still exists

Comment: is your code editor showing suggestions for autocomplete while typing import pandas?